# Loop through and print out all the data in redb

Tags: json, database, rust

Please help, I have a problem that I don't know how to solve: I have a redb database file and I want to use rust to open and read it.

```
use redb::{Database, Error, ReadableTable, TableDefinition};

const TABLE: TableDefinition<u64, u64> = TableDefinition::new("my_data");

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {

    println!("In file 1111");

    let db = Database::create("int_keys.redb")?;
    let write_txn = db.begin_write()?;
    {
        let mut table = write_txn.open_table(TABLE)?;
        table.insert(&0, &0)?;
    }
    write_txn.commit()?;

    let read_txn = db.begin_read()?;
    let table = read_txn.open_table(TABLE)?;
    assert_eq!(table.get(&0 )?.unwrap().value(), 0);
    println!("{}", table.get(&0)?.unwrap().value());

    println!("In f{}", table.len()?);

    let mut iter = table.range(0..1).unwrap();
    for i in 3 {
        let (key, value) = iter.next().unwrap();
        assert_eq!(i, key);
        assert_eq!(i, value);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjRBn.jpg)

I don't quite understand the official documentation inside and don't know how to properly write rust read redb traversal: https://docs.rs/redb/latest/redb/trait.ReadableTable.html#tymethod.range

Comment: Please don't post images of errors. Post the output of `cargo check` *as text*.

Comment: hi，kmdreko：here is the error output

let (key, value) = iter.next().unwrap();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^   -------------------- this expression has type `Result<(AccessGuard<'_, u64>, AccessGuard<'_, u64>), redb::Error>`

expected `Result<(AccessGuard<'_, u64>, ...), ...>`, found `(_, _)`

Comment: Include the error *in your post* and not as a comment, its fairly illegible here

Comment: And the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.